# Quotations not working in PostgreSQL Queries

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql

I have the following table

```
create table players (name varchar(30), playerid serial primary key);
```

And I am working with the script:

```
def registerPlayer(name):
    """Registers new player."""
    db = psycopg2.connect("dbname=tournament")
    c = db.cursor()
    player = "insert into players values (%s);"
    scores = "insert into scores (wins, matches) values (0, 0);"
    c.execute(player, (name,))
    c.execute(scores)
    db.commit()
    db.close()
```

But when I try and register a player with the argument in quotes as so:

```
registerPlayer("Any Name")
```

It doesn't work... Now, if I directly enter the query into psql, it works if I only use single quotes as so

```
INSERT INTO players VALUES ('Any Name');
```

But not if I use "Any Name". If I use the "", it tells me:

```
ERROR:  column "Any Name" does not exist
```

Now, this is a problem if I want to enter a name in such as Bob O'Neal, because it will close off that entry after the O.
The quotes were working fine the other day, and I went to format so that all the SQL queries were capitalized, and everything stopped working. I returned to the code that was working fine, and now nothing is working!

Comment: `INSERT INTO players VALUES ('"Any Name"');` furtherore you have to follow columns ordering or set column names explicitly. - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-insert.html

Answer (score 2):

Double-quotes in SQL are not strings - they escape table, index, and other object names (ex. `"John Smith"` refers to a table named `John Smith`). Only single quoted strings are actually strings.

In any case, if you are using query parameters properly (which, in your example code, you seem to be), you should not have to worry about escaping your data. Simply pass the raw values to `execute` (ex. `c.execute(player, ("Bob O'Niel",))`)

Comment: So the function is as so: registerPlayer("Bob O'Niel"), but it still isn't registering.